# How to decrypt Kwvnqlmvbqitqbg?

Tags: encryption, decryption

How would I go about to decrypt the above string, if I do not know what cipher was used?

Comment: Isn't it caesar cipher +8? Results into:  Confidentiality

Answer (score 5):

It's encrypted using a **Ceasar Cipher** and a Key of 8. Encryption with Caesar code is a simple substitution (one letter replaces another). Caesar code replaces each letter with an alphabet shift: a letter further in the alphabet. To decrypt we just reverse that substitution.

The plaintext for Kwvnqlmvbqitqbg is "CONFIDENTIALITY".

Best way to go about decrypting this is

1. See that this is still readable plaintext and most likely a simple substitution.
2. When we know the language used, we can use the a frequency analysis to find out which letter in the cipher is most likely to represent the most popular letters in that language. This is a short text, so this won't help too much.
3. Easiest solution is to just try all the keys because there only are only 26 letters in the alphabet.

There are also online services that encrypt/decrypt Ceasar cipher like: https://www.dcode.fr/caesar-cipher

Comment: While you are right about the Caesar cypher I think the best way to decrypt it is not to try all the keys, this could take a long time before you find the one you need. Id say trow it in an online decryptor. Not entirely sure why your answer got downvoted tho